# Not able to execute the query in java

Tags: java, sql

I'm executing the query,

```
SELECT  
  UNIQUE PXCID,SNCID,FREQUENCY 
FROM 
  AFFECTEDXCS 
WHERE 
  PTPNAME IN ('AM2125A-1-14-LINEIN','AM2125A-1-15-LINEOUT','CWR-7-14-CLS2') 
AND FREQUENCY='9170' and NENAME='CP0MP1-121-N2-SITE3' 
ORDER BY SNCID;
```

from SQL Developer, it gives me row of value?

Same query i'm trying to execute it from java with the code.

```
String query =  DBStatements.PXCID_LIST;
        Object[] param = new Object[3];
        param[0]="AM2125A-1-14-LINEIN,AM2125A-1-15-LINEOUT,CWR-7-14-CLS2";
        param[1]=frequency;
        param[2]=nodelabel;
List<Map<String,Object>> returnList = eqmqueryexec.executeQuery(EQMDataSource.OTN, "0", query, param);
        Iterator<Map<String,Object>> iter = returnList.iterator();
        logger.debug("iterator bolean length"+iter.hasNext());
```

I'm getting the "iterator bolean length" as false. That's means the query as not executed properly?

Comment: Or that it returns a list of length: 0

Comment: yes. The return list length is 0

Comment: Given that the query text named `EQMDataSource.OTN` is using bound parameters like `?`, then yes, the is most likely running correctly if it returns an empty list. Can you post `EQMDataSource.OTN` for us to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every params you need to bind withing IN clause should be individual question marks rather than only one que. mark for whole IN clause.. like

> SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_id IN(?,?,?,?,?)

and you have to bind variable for each param separately..